# After login it won't to navigate me to the other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a problem now because it won't navigate me after I click log in, it takes cookies, but won't relocate. You can show my components look right now. Everything is fine, except when I click log in, it won't relocates me to the home page.

Components:

`<App />` component

```
function App() {
 const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
 const [login, setLogin] = useState()

  return (
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Routes>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes login={login}  userData= 
      {userData} />}>
        <Route element={<Home />} path="/" exact />
        <Route element={<Products />} path="/products" />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<Login setUserData={setUserData} setLogin= 
      {setLogin} />} 
      path="/login" />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
  </div>
 );
 }
```

`<Login />` component

```
const Login = ({ setUserData }) => {
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true)
const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");

Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const login = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
  username: username,
  password: password,
}).then((response) => {
  setUserData(response.data);
  navigate("/");
});
```

};

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userData?.loggedIn) {
    navigate("/");
  }
   }, [userData]);
```

}

```
return (
<div>
  <div>Prijava</div>
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={login}>
      <label>Korisničko ime</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setUsername(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <label>Lozinka</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPassword(e.target.value);
        }}
      ></input>
      <button>Prijavi se</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  );
  };
```

`<PrivateRoutes />` component

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({userData, login}) => {


 return !login ? <p>Checking...</p>: userData?.loggedIn ? <Outlet 
 /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;    

  };
```

Console log error, after implementing code.

[image]

Newest `App` and `PrivateRoutes` version

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page loads, `userData` is not set, because the `useEffect` runs after the JSX is rendered. Hence your condition is falling to `<Navigate to="/login" />` instead of `<Outlet/>`.

You could use an additional state, called `checking`, for example, use it to display some loading message while the data is fetched.

Also, move the `useEffect` to check the login state on load inside `PrivateRoutes`. Changes your components as follows.

App:

```
function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login")
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.loggedIn == true) {
          setUserData(response.data);
        }
        return;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setChecking(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes userData={userData} checking={checking} />}>
            <Route element={<Home />} path="/" exact />
            <Route element={<Products />} path="/products" />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<Login setUserData={setUserData} userData={userData} />} path="/login" />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PrivateRoutes:

```js
const PrivateRoutes = ({ userData, checking }) => {
  return checking ? <p>Checking...</p> : userData?.loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};
```

Login:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = ({ setUserData, userData }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    }).then((response) => {
      setUserData(response.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
     navigate("/");
    }
  }, [userData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>Prijava</div>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={login}>
            <label>Korisničko ime</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUsername(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <label>Lozinka</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setPassword(e.target.value);
              }}
            ></input>
            <button>Prijavi se</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue with the userData state being undefined during the initial render, you can initialize it with a default value in the state declaration, for example:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ loggedIn: false });
```

Additionally, you can wrap the conditional rendering in a useEffect hook that depends on userData:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userData?.loggedIn) {
    // Render the Outlet component
  } else {
    // Render the Navigate component
  }
}, [userData]);
```

Comment: The `useEffect` hook is for issuing intentional side-effects, not rendering any UI.